# Inflection point and 3rd derivative f'''(x)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given f(x), by wikipedia, the sufficient existence condition for x = `c` to be an *inflection point* is:

> f″(c + ε) and f″(c − ε) to have opposite signs in the neighborhood of c.

Is that equal to:

`f''(c) = 0`, and `f'''(c) != 0` ?

Answer (score 1):

Take $$f(x)=x^5$$

$(0,0) $ is an inflection point of the curve $ C_f $ but
$$\;\; f'''(0)=0$$

Comment: Your description fit the the conclusion of my question, `f′′′(x)=6` -> `f′′′(x)!=0`. `!=` means not equals.

Comment: @user218867 Replace $ x^3$ by $ x^5$.

Comment: Ok, get it, any suggestion on easily finding out whether `f″(c + ε) and f″(c − ε) to have opposite signs in the neighborhood of c.`?

Comment: @user218867 It depends on $ c $.

Answer (score 0):

inflection points occur at the points when the function switches concavity. Concave up corresponds to positive second derivate and concave down has a negative 2nd derivative. So at infection points, 2nd derivate must be $0$. So inflection points occur when the second derivate changes signs. The third derivative is the rate at which the second derivative is changing. So, when the third derivate is $0$,  the second derivative is constant and the rate of slope changing is fixed.

Hope this helps you figure it out!

Comment: `!=` means not equal.